# Using socket io and canvas, store datas by id

Tags: javascript, paperjs

Im totally new to stack (and forums) so apologies if im missing thing :p

So I'm using socket io to store the infos of my canvas drawings, and I want to store my datas like this

```
 global{
    session
        cursor{
            x
            y
        }
        line{
            id 
            infos{
                x
                y
                radius
                color
                type
            }
        }
}
```

At the moment I have a "`onMouseDrag`" function

```
function onMouseDrag(event) {
    var id = myPath.id;
    var type = event.type;
    var x = event.middlePoint.x;
    var y = event.middlePoint.y;
    var color = "red";
    drawItem( x, y, color );
    EnvoieOnMouseDraging( x, y, color,type,id );
}
```

which call this function :

```
function EnvoieOnMouseDraging( x, y, color,type,id) {
    var data = {
        id: id,
        infos: {
            x: x,
            y: y,
            color: color,
            type: type,
            id: id
        }
    };

    io.emit( 'drawCircle', data)
}
```

So its working fine but if you watch the result which is logged I have something like this

[infos stored in nodeserver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKuyS.png)

As you can see it create multiple objects with same id.

Now what I wanna do is to store all the datas with the same id in one object. In that case one path will be an object and i will be able to delete the last path.

If you think I don't clear enough go to the good direction and if you have an easiest way to do that I'm up.

Thanks guys,
cheers

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is just to aggregate your informations by Id you can easily store your data in an Array like, maybe 2D Array where the first index is your ID then each informations.

```
  ///
  // if I have a record in the current Id then push new information
  // if not, set my 2DArray as new Array with information at the
  // current Id as Array
  ///

  myArray[myId]?myArray[myId].push(infos):myArray[myId] = [infos];
```

Then you may can store information by the event and emit/store them in a mouseUp event( when user finished to draw ) you may see an example here (look at the console output) :https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqEzVL

First, in the drag event you store every movement, then on the mouseUp event you can store your datas and you can retrieve them by the Id.

Note you can store index as string (as Javascript Objects) because numbers will create rows for nothing.

Only a rought, but I hope you can think about a proper way to store your datas

Comment: But in that case thé drawing wont be in real Time? It Will appear at thé end of the drawing. Because we're waiting for the user to onMouseUp to send thé datas to thé server?

Comment: Oh ok my bad, then you have to send datas as previously done but aggregate in an Array server side when you recieve the emit maybe.